# Matlab Code for Linear System by Central Difference Method

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a linear system Ay = b, which is created by matrix looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Here attempt to find the curves based on the matrix in the image description:

```
n  = 10;
x0 = 0;
xn = 1;
h  = 1/n;
y0 = 0;
y1 = 0;

x  = zeros(1:n-1);
for i = 1:n-1;
    x(i) = i*h
end

A =zeros(n-1);
for j = 1:n-2;
    A(j,j+1) = (1+h/2);
    A(j,j) = (h*exp(x(j))-2);
    A(j+1,j) = (1-h/2);
end
A(n-1,n-1) = (h*exp(x(n-1))-2);

b = zeros(1,n-1);        %Right-hand side vector
for i = 1:n-1
    b(i)=h^2*((exp(x(i))-pi^2)*sin(pi*x(i))+pi*cos(pi*x(i)));
end
b=b';

y = zeros(1,n-1);
y = inv(A)*b                  % Solving for y
figure
plot(x,y,x,sin(x))
```

This is code that I create but the curves disappear, anyone can help me to check my code?

Comment: Apparently it seems that you wanted to pre-allocate memory for `x` like this: `x  = zeros(1, n-1);`

Comment: The curve was appear when I pre-allocate memory for x, but the curves different with my teacher did at class